# Why isn't the getdate stored in the database?

Tags: php, joomla

Here is my function, and the  date

```
$data->datecreated = getdate();
```

at the bellow code won't get saved in the database. Why?
Notice that the record gets inserted, but the datecreated field looks like is ignored

```
public function generateCode($characters) {

        //Generate the code
        $possible = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
        $code = '';
        $i = 0;

        while ($i < $characters) {
            $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
            $i++;
        }
        // Get the curent session id of the user        
        $session =  JFactory::getSession();
        $session_id = $session->getId();        

        //Create an stdClass
        $data =new stdClass();
        $data->sessionid = (integer)$session_id;
        $data->captchacode = (string)$code;     
        $data->datecreated = getdate();

        $db = JFactory::getDBO();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->delete($db->nameQuote('#__captchasessions'));
        $query->where($db->nameQuote('sessionid').'='.$db->quote($session_id));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->query();

        $db->insertObject( '#__captchasessions', $data, id );       

        return $code;
    }
```

This is the structure of the table

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `ok6ut_captchasessions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sessionid` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `captchacode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datecreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Comment: Tell us what happens and where. PHP errors? MySQL errors?

Comment: No error, It just ignores the entry, but the rest gets inserted

Comment: you dont need to use `$db = JFactory::getDBO();` twice

Comment: not sure if this will make a difference but try `$data->datecreated = JFactory::getDate()` instead

Comment: nope, only $data->datecreated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getdate()` returns an array with details of the current date in it, if there's no timestamp passed in as a parameter.

I expect that your database is expecting a formatted date to be passed in, and not an array - if you could add your database structure, that might help.

Edited to add:

For a datetime field, I think you need something like:

```
$data->datecreated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```